# Email OTP verification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I am new to react js and firebase so I don't know how to get OTP through email. This code is only  sending verification link to email but I want OTP in email.What changes I have to make in this code for getting OTP.
Here is the Code-

```
const signup = () => {
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // send verification mail.
      userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
      //auth.signOut();
      alert("Email sent");
    })
    .catch(alert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication currently only supports sending an OTP (for [multi-factor authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/multi-factor)) through SMS messages. Sending an OTP through email is not supported.

It's a valid request though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it.